# Only show result of sql query on database table1 if there is a value in table 2

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli

I am busy creating a website that allows people to host dinners and allows users to join those dinners. I have two different database tables called gebruikers (users) and diner (dinner). I am working on a search page that makes it possible for a user to search on a woonplaats (city) and then shows the users living in that city. That works right now, but I want to make sure that only the users are shown who have added a dinner. There is a common key in both tables: diner.gebruikersid = gebruikers.id 
So in other words, I only want the users with their ID in both the diner and the gebruikers table to be displayed in the search results. How can I do that?

I have this code at the moment:

```
$zoeken = $_POST['woonplaats'];
    $sql = "SELECT id, voornaam, straatnaam FROM gebruikers WHERE woonplaats LIKE '$zoeken'"; 
    $result = mysql_query($sql); 



    echo "<div class=res>"; 
    echo "<h3>Resulaten voor " .$zoeken. "</h3>";
    echo "<table>";
    echo "<thead>";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<th>Voornaam</th>";
    echo "<th>Straatnaam</th>";
    echo "<th></th>"; 
    echo "</tr>";
    echo "</thead>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo "<tbody>";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>".$row['voornaam']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['straatnaam']."</td>";
    echo "<td>";
    echo "<form action='eetprofiel.php' method='post'>";
    echo "<input type='hidden' name='id' value='".$row['id']."'>";
    echo "<input type='submit' value='Profiel bekijken'>"; 
    echo "</form>";
    echo "<td>"; 
    echo "</tr>";
    echo "</tbody>";
}


    echo "</table>";
    echo "</div>";



?>
```

Edit:

[These are all the users in my database (in table gebruikers) with woonplaats Amersfoort](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m8QzJ.jpg)

[These are all the diners submitted by those users.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U8SVD.jpg)

As you see, the user with gebruikers.id and diner.gebruikersid 23 has no dinner submitted, so I don't want him to be shown in the search results.

Comment: read something about SQL INNER JOIN.

Comment: Please take a look at mysqli or pdo because mysql is deprecated

Comment: @etsa I know it has to do with inner join, but I can't figure out how to use that for this cause because I don't want to get any data from the diner table, I just want to display a user only IF he has his ID in the dinner table. Could you explain a little more specific where I should look?

Comment: if you need more help, please report some test data and output expected.  It will be easier to help you.

Comment: @etsa I have edited my answer. Could only post two links. This is the 3rd image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ad7Yv.jpg 
That is the result I am currently receiving. I don't want the user with id 23 to be shown in the results as he isn't in the diner table.

Comment: please, make an effort and create a sample of data in text form (you can see demo in stackoverflow tutorial or in other questions).

Answer (score 0):

You should join the 2 tables. With JOIN take a look at this

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-using-joins.htm

example of a join

```
select tableA.user ,tableB.user from tableA JOIN tableB on tableA.id = tableB.id
```

note: don't use mysql it is deprecated use mysqli or PDO instead

Comment: I know it has to do with inner join, and I am familiar with that. But I can't figure out how to use that for this cause because I don't want to get any data from the diner table, I just want to display a user only IF he has his ID in the dinner table. Could you explain a little more specificly where I should look?